# Unable to replicate Predict/NeuralNetwork example from Help Pages

Tags: warning-messages, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to replicate an example right out of the help manual (`ref/method/NeuralNetwork`).  This example compares the convolutional NN versus a fully-connected NN.  I am using *Mathematica* 11.3 on Linux 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04.

```
data = Table[
   x -> x^2 + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {x, 
    RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 50]}];
dataplot = ListPlot[List @@@ data];

fullyconnectedpredictor = 
 Predict[data, 
  Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "NetworkType" -> "FullyConnected"}]

convolutionalpredictor = 
 Predict[data, 
  Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "NetworkType" -> "Convolutional"}]
```

The help manual provides the following plot as comparison:

```
Show[dataplot, 
 Plot[{fullyconnectedpredictor[x], 
   convolutionalpredictor[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"FullyConnected", "Convolutional"}]]
```

[image]

Running the **same** example (in the help page) gives me a completely different and horrible result:

[image]

I thought maybe it was a Mathematica kernel issue and I restarted my computer and launched a fresh instance of Mathematica.

What happened here?  Am I overlooking something?  As an added note, if I were to change the `Method->"NearestNeighbor"` or `"GradientBoostedTrees"`, it works just fine.

Comment: Works Fine In Mac @ Wolfram Mathematica 12.0

Comment: OK in version 12.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: I get the exact result on OSX mm v12 aswell...cannot replicate